# How to let a tkinter button return it's text value

Tags: python, button, tkinter

So I have this code and want the button to return it's text value when being clicked.

```
film = ['Woezel & Pip Op zoek naar de Sloddervos!', 'The White Snake',
        'Proof of Life', 'Rise of the Planet of the Apes',
        'Mona Lisa Smile', '2 Guns', 'Max Payne', 'De eetclub']

for item in film:
    button = Button(master=aanbiederspage, text=item, 
                    command=filmdatabase).pack()
```

Comment: where do you expect it to return the value to?

Comment: well like the function "filmdatabase" is going to write the text of the button to a txt file

Comment: Is it me or right now you're just creating a single button object with the last `item` in the list `film`? I think you need to clarify your question a bit.

Comment: This what I currently have creates buttons with the name of the movie's on them. I want it to be when being clicked that the title of the name is writen with the "filmdatabase" function

Comment: Ok, so what you're asking is not how to _return_ the value _from_ the command, but rather how to _pass_ the name of the film _to_ the command. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to pass the `item` string to the `command` callback, but you have to be careful how you do this. One way is to make the `item` string a default arg to a `lambda` function. It has to be a default arg so that `item` gets bound to that arg when the `lambda` is defined. If we just did `lambda : func(item)` then every button would print the last item in the list. That happens because in that case Python looks up the *current* value of `item` when the callback is called.

```
import tkinter as tk

film = ['Woezel & Pip Op zoek naar de Sloddervos!', 'The White Snake',
    'Proof of Life', 'Rise of the Planet of the Apes', 'Mona Lisa Smile', 
    '2 Guns', 'Max Payne', 'De eetclub']

def func(item):
    print(item)

root = tk.Tk()

for item in film:
    tk.Button(master=root, text=item, command=lambda s=item: func(s)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Note how in my code I *don't* do `button = tk.Button(`... There's no point making that assignment. Firstly, we aren't saving those widgets anywhere, but more importantly, `.pack` returns `None`, so doing

```
button = Button(master=aanbiederspage, text=item, command=filmdatabase).pack()
```

actually sets `button` to `None`, not to the Button widget.

Answer (score -1):

You can use lambda with command to send arguments to 'filmdatabase': it should look something like this:

```
for item in film:
    button = Button(master=aanbiederspage, text=item, command= lambda: filmdatabase(item)).pack()
```

Comment: Using this command only the last value in the list film is being writen in the file. And not the text of the button.